# Can static charge on a fan blade affect how air flows over it?

Tags: electrostatics, fluid-dynamics

So there is this hypothesis that the reason why fan blades accumulate so much dust [click here to see why](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/why-does-dust-stick-to-rotating-fan-propeller)

I was thinking what would happen if I did the opposite. Let's say if I attach the blades to a high voltage using carbon brushes. How would the flow of air change like weather it would become more laminar or turbulent, how it affects the efficiency, or how it affects the capacity of vacuum pumps or compressors which use blades like centrifugal/turbo molecular etc.
Also we can test if the applied high voltage is AC or DC produce different effects, weather the frequency of the AC and RPM of the blades have any correlation on efficiency, metal blades or plastic blades.

**Can you predict theoretically what would happen under each of  these or other circumstances which may come to your mind?**

Has anyone studied and reported on this phenomenon before? If so can you please link it?

Extra: So since quite a while I was mentally designing some experiments and almost all of them required a powerful vacuum pump which could atleast get as low as 10^-5 torr. All the modern solution like a turbo molecular pump or oil diffusion pump are way out of my budget and sprengel pump will require a lot of mercury, not possible. So I came across a pump with a extraordinary working principle.[Boundary-effect Pump](https://hackaday.io/project/8171-everymans-turbomolecular-pump)
If you go through the article in the link you will see the absurd specifications he has calculated for the pump to get to 10^-7 torr. Such specifications are impossible to be met cheaply but I was thinking if statically charging the disc would increase the boundary effect thereby allowing high vacuum to be achieved at lower speeds.

Comment: If you voltage is high enough and the blades have sharp enough points, you can ionize the air and produce ion wind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_wind

Comment: @Yrogirg That is an interesting idea. Thanks for replying to such a old question.