# Why is the top surface of a ceiling fan more dusty than the bottom?

Tags: electrostatics, fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, drag

[image: fan top]

*Top surface of a ceiling fan ( that hasn't been cleaned for a long time)*

---

[image: fan bottom]

*The bottom surface*

---

The top surface seems to be way more dusty than the bottom. I reason that it doesn't have anything to do with gravity, as I've seen pretty much the same results on table fan propellors and exhaust fans,  which has a horizontal axis of rotation. What else could be the reason?

Comment: Related question: [Why does dust stick to rotating fan propeller?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1343/179151)

Comment: I would challenge the assertion that table fans with a horizontal axis suffer from significantly more dust build-up on one side of the blades. I haven't noticed that effect personally (although I will look out for it from now). Do you have any reference to support that claim?

Comment: @Time4Tea I can't say if I've noticed that either.    I've noticed dusty blades, but if my memory is correct, the dust buildup seemed fairly uniform on either side.

Comment: @Time4Tea I thought this sight would be very common! I would be surprised if it was not. Since I don't have access to a table fan in the present context; I can't give any solid evidence for the same. But anyway, let me add that you can observe this better on an exhaust fan. Maybe someone else on the site can verify?

Comment: Not a solid evidence, but I found a video on YouTube about cleaning a vertical fan.( https://youtu.be/J2HrSNaeiJY) I've the screenshots of the scenes when the lady shows us the two surfaces of the propellers. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyBgu.gif

Comment: I have noticed this as well, I am fairly certain it's because of blades' shape. Pay attention to that curvature at edges.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=QXGDcFBcrQQ

Comment: The video shows a sideways fan with both sides dirty, more so the front--where the air hits is the dirtiest, except with a ceiling fan where gravity prevents buildup on the bottom, and adds to buildup on top.

Comment: And I have cleaned fans multiple times, I get the same results, the buildup is not mostly on the back unless it's a ceiling fan. Gravity is the culprit

Comment: Could it depend on the blade angle and direction of rotation?

Comment: Ceiling fans can go in reverse. They still collect dust on top. If it is dirty enough some dust will build up on the bottom, but not so much compared to the top. All fans collect dust on the edge where air hits.

Comment: My interpretation of the answers to the question referenced by @AaronStevens is that the surfaces of the fan near the regions of highest wind shear (curl) accumulate the most dust. This is because the air has a roughly constant density of dust, so parts of the fan exposed to more air accumulate the most dust. This argument is used to explain why the leading edge of a blade is dustier than the trailing edge, but I don’t know whether/why regions near the top of the fan might experience higher wind shear than the bottom.

Comment: @user47014 It seems like you should just post an answer :)

Comment: @AaronStevens I got excited when I realized my computer was really dusty and has 3 sets of fans.  I thought I had a good working idea of what to expect based on blade angle, rotation direction and airflow.  Sadly it only led to much more confusion.  Before I even checked the dust, I was getting suction on fans that I could swear should be exhausting air... and the dust even implied exhaust to me.  I probably could have tried to analyze it further; but I decided instead to just close the computer back up before I started rearranging all the fans and taking everything apart.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That are many factors at play here.
Let us consider the case when the fan is rotating.Since there is a suction of air towards the bottom in the top surface of the fan the dust particle which move along the air flow collides with the top surface of the fan.On the contrary the dust particles get pushed away from the bottom surface of fan.This makes the top part more dusty.

[image: Fig 1]

---

According to this idea there should not be any dust on the bottom surface at all.But this is not the case. Since the fan blade is slightly slanted some dust particles below the fan obliquely collides with it.

[image: Fig 2]

Now consider the case when the fan is at rest.Assuming that the composition of dust particles in the room is uniform and the motion is somewhat random,both the surfaces of the blades gather almost the same amount of dust.But amount of dust will be slightly more on the top because of gravity. This explains why the bottom surface also has a little amount of dust.

Hope this explanation is satisfactory